# How to achieve more than 250 characters input in Dialogflow(api.ai)

Tags: dialogflow-es

When using dialog flow intents, some scenarios we need to give Text inputs to send to Webhook. In that case if the size of the text exceeds 250 bytes, dialogflow is throwing error. My question is how to achieve giving input text to intents which are more than 250 bytes. Thanks

Comment: I'm curious of your use case where you need to pass more than 250 characters? That many characters doesn't sound like its "conversational".

Comment: Accepting URL inputs, especially from social network such as Facebook, gives us very long URL's. As of one year later, this limit still exists, and I'm still hoping for any workaround available.

Comment: Example use case:  Our phone-based Geneys-integrated Dialogflow app asks the caller to "briefly describe their situation". The speech-to-text results in more than 250 chars frequently, so we were forced to pass control back to Genesys to handle it.  Not a pretty solution.

Answer (score 5):

The limitation is 256 bytes, as referenced [here in the docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions/detectIntent#TextInput).

Comment: Moved [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/QueryInput#TextInput)